# Mathematical definition of implicit vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm reading a paper in which the term "implicit vectors" is mentioned with regards to a vector space. Specifically "can be modelled as vector space $E_h$ and implicit vectors $e_h$" as quoted from the screenshot. However, I cannot find a mathematical definition of "implicit vectors". What is the mathematical definition of an "implicit vector"?

[Relevant screenshot from the paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gayxt.png)

Comment: Where was this article published, out of curiosity? I don't know anything about machine learning, but my guess is that "implicit" here means something like "fully determined but possibly difficult to compute (explicitly)"

Comment: @ElliotG, I found the article from arXiv.org: https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.11371, the line in question falls in section IV-B4